# How to check which class an item is in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a function that is passed an item, the item could be either one of two object classes. I'm trying to test the item for a variable that only exists in one of the classes to identify which of the two classes it is. I'm not sure what the correct way to do this is. I'm trying:

```
    let theItem = item as! ObjectOne
    if let objectOneUniqueVariable = theItem.uniqueVariable {
        print("It's an instance of ObjectOne")
        //Do more things
    } else {
        theItem = item as! ObjectTwo
        print("It's an instance of ObjectTwo")
        //Do more things
    }
```

The uniqueVariable is a sting - I'm currently getting the error:

Initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

I can add what ever I need to Object One in order for this test to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has an elegant solution: Switch on the class type.

```
switch item {
  case let object1 as ObjectOne:
    print("It's an instance of ObjectOne")
    //Do more things
  case let object2 as ObjectTwo:
    print("It's an instance of ObjectTwo")
    //Do more things
  default:
    println("something else")
}
```

In the minimal case if you only cared about getting the value if it's the type of object1, a minimalist way of getting an optional is:

```
let optionalValue = (item as? ObjectOne)?.theMember
```

You could then unwrap it, if/when you need it.

Comment: Great, this is perfect. Thanks!